# BPF/XDP: Why does `bpf_ntohs` produce verifier error?

Tags: c, linux, xdp-bpf

I have a problem with the BPF/XDP verifier. I try to filter UDP packets and write a timestamp at the end of the packet (with `udh->len`). Because `udh->len` is in network byte order I first have to convert it to "host" byteorder. So I tried it like this:

```
SEC("xdp_sock")
int xdp_sock_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {

    const void *data = (void*)(unsigned long)ctx->data;
    const void *data_end = (void*)(unsigned long)ctx->data_end;

    const struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*)(data);

    if((void*)eth + sizeof(struct ethhdr) <= data_end) {

        if(bpf_ntohs(eth->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP) {
            const struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

            if((void*)iph + sizeof(struct iphdr) <= data_end) {

                if(iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
                    const __u16 iph_sz_in_bytes = iph->ihl * IP_HDR_MULT_IHL;

                    if((void*)iph + iph_sz_in_bytes <= data_end) {

                        const struct udphdr *udh = (struct udphdr*)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iph_sz_in_bytes);

                        if((void*)udh + sizeof(struct udphdr) <= data_end) {
                            const __u16 udh_sz_in_bytes = bpf_ntohs(udh->len);

                            if((void*)udh + udh_sz_in_bytes <= data_end) {
                                bpf_printk("HELLO!\n");
                                /* Usually I would start to write the timestamp here */
                            }
```

But I get `math between pkt pointer and register with unbounded min value is not allowed`.

Because I couldn't thought of a way where this would fail I tried to remove `bpf_ntohs` just for testing purposes (I know that it wouldn't work that way):

```
SEC("xdp_sock")
int xdp_sock_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {

    const void *data = (void*)(unsigned long)ctx->data;
    const void *data_end = (void*)(unsigned long)ctx->data_end;

    const struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*)(data);

    if((void*)eth + sizeof(struct ethhdr) <= data_end) {

        if(bpf_ntohs(eth->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP) {
            const struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

            if((void*)iph + sizeof(struct iphdr) <= data_end) {

                if(iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
                    const __u16 iph_sz_in_bytes = iph->ihl * IP_HDR_MULT_IHL;

                    if((void*)iph + iph_sz_in_bytes <= data_end) {

                        const struct udphdr *udh = (struct udphdr*)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iph_sz_in_bytes);

                        if((void*)udh + sizeof(struct udphdr) <= data_end) {
                            const __u16 udh_sz_in_bytes = udh->len;

                            if((void*)udh + udh_sz_in_bytes <= data_end) {
                                bpf_printk("HELLO!\n");
                            }
```

But I am actually able to run my program this way - any ideas why `bpf_ntohs` produces a verifier error?

Comment: `udh + udh_sz_in_bytes` is probably where the math happens, I suppose `bpf_ntohs()` prevents the verifier to determine min bound for `udh_sz_in_bytes` somehow. Maybe try adding something like `if (udh_sz_in_bytes < 8) return;` before the `if((void*)udh + udh_sz_in_bytes <= data_end)`? Otherwise, have a look at the detailed debug info from the verifier and try to understand the difference between your two versions?

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: do early returns instead of cascade nesting. It'll make code easier to follow.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't do `void*` arithmetic. I think gcc and clang let you get away with it, but it's still UB.